# How to install the Jinja2 template engine for a specific version of Python when a few are available on the system?

Tags: python, ubuntu, jinja2

Ubuntu ships with a few different versions of Python out of the box. When I type *python* in the terminal window and press *Tab*, I get this:

```
python      python2.7   python3.4   python3m    
python2     python3     python3.4m
```

So, if I want my code to be run under Python version 3, I would issue the following command:

```
python3 script.py
```

But how can I download and install the Jinja2 template engine specifically for my Python 3? And I have the pip utility installed.

Comment: Run the version of pip for python 3, which is probably pip3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Already figured that out. Use these commands to get pip and Jija2 installed for Python 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install Jinja2
```

Comment: /Users/rshenoy/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages - Adding to this location. I wanted to install for python3

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you found on your own, there is a system that alliws you to install packages on a per project basis with a defined interpreter version call virtual environments. Many developers use it.

Have look at [this introduction](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and see if it fits your needs and workflow.